# System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, http, iis

I want to sent push notification via parse.com and i have webservice like that

[WebMethod]
    public bool pushNotification(string pushMessage) 
    {
        bool isPushMessageSend = false;

```
    string postString = "";
    string urlpath = "https://api.parse.com/1/push";
    //var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlpath);

    System.Net.WebRequest request = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(urlpath);

    request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

    request.PreAuthenticate = true;

    request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;




    postString = "{ \"channels\": [ \"Trials\"  ], " +
                     "\"data\" : {\"alert\":\"" + pushMessage + "\"}" +
                     "}";
    request.ContentType = "application/json";
    request.ContentLength = postString.Length;
    request.Headers.Add("APP ID", "My Parse App Id");
    request.Headers.Add("REST API KEY", "My Rest API Key");
    request.Method = "POST";
    StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
    requestWriter.Write(postString);
    requestWriter.Close();
    //var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    System.Net.WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        var responseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        JObject jObjRes = JObject.Parse(responseText);
        if (Convert.ToString(jObjRes).IndexOf("true") != -1)
        {
            isPushMessageSend = true;
        }
    }

    return isPushMessageSend;
}
```

I had error like this

```
System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at WebService.pushNotification(String pushMessage) in c:\Users\Hurkan Seyhan\desktop\website3\App_Code\WebService.cs:line 488
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to their documentation (https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#sending-channels/REST) I think that mistake in your headers

instead of

```
request.Headers.Add("[YOUR APP ID]", "My Parse App Id");
request.Headers.Add("[YOUR REST API KEY]", "My Rest API Key");
```

you probably should write the following:

```
request.Headers.Add("X-Parse-Application-Id", "[YOUR APP ID]");
request.Headers.Add("X-Parse-REST-API-Key", "[YOUR REST API KEY]");
```

Comment: do you know how can i send notification to  all users without specify channel

Comment: Please check the "Using Advanced Targeting" section in documentation which available by link I already provided in my answer